# Ionic 3 Storage Timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I am loading some json from storage and intend to display the information in the page html template. However when I do so, upon entering the page I get errors implicating that the information is not (yet) available.

I may have misunderstood the concept but is it possible to make a synchronized call to ionic storage instead of the async one? I basically want to check if a profile is stored on the device, if not -> push back to login screen. But apparently the call to ionic storage takes too long and is **not yet** resolved when the page is loaded.

page.ts

```
private user:User;
constructor(private storage: Storage) {   
    storage.get('user').then(data => {
      this.user = data;
    });
  }
```

page.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div>
    <p>Welcome <b>{{user.name}}</b></p>    
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

As I said this will give me the error that user.name is undefined.
When using the ngif directive to wait for the promise to be resolved it works.
But I think I misunderstood the concept here.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div *ngIf="user">
    <p>Welcome <b>{{user.name}}</b></p>    
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

So how can I make a call to Ionic Storage and have the data available when the page is loaded/entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> may have misunderstood the concept but is it possible to make a
>   synchronized call to ionic storage instead of the async one?

This is an async operation, I don't think you can do this in a sync way.
Either way your solution to use ***ngIf="user"** Is a good a solution, you can also add something like

```
  <div *ngIf="!user">
     //Load a spinner, or a loading bar
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It'is just because it takes a bit of time to get the user from storage.

Another suggestion to avoid errors without the *ng-if:

```
private user:User = new User(); // Initialize the user property

constructor(private storage: Storage) {   
    storage.get('user').then(data => {
        this.user = Object.assign(new User, data);
    });
}
```